# How to integrate- : $e^{|x|}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Q)How to integrate $$\int e^{|x|}dx$$?

Ans) First of all let me tell everyone that this question suddenly came in my mind because in my school life I have learnt how to integrate $\int e^{x}dx$ and also I have learnt how to integrate $\int e^{-x}dx$. The result of $\int e^{x}dx=e^{x}+C$ and the result of $\int e^{-x}dx=-e^{-x}+C$. I am not showing the step by step solutions of these questions because these questions are very much easy. The solutions are also of a single step. Now let me come into my question.

$1^{st}$ process:

We know that the definition of $|x|$ is

$$f(x)=|x|=
  \begin{cases}
  x,  & \text{if $x>0$} \\[2ex]
  0,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\[2ex]                                                                   
 -x,  & \text{if $x<0$}
 \end{cases}
$$.
Therefore the definition of $e^{|x|}$ will be
$$f(x)=e^{|x|}=
  \begin{cases}
  e^{x}, & \text{if $x>0$} \\[2ex]
  1    , & \text{if $x=0$} \\[2ex]
\frac{1}{e^{x}}, & \text{if $x<0$} \\[2ex]
  \end{cases}
$$.
Therefore, there will be $3$ results occuring for $\int e^{|x|}dx$.

When $x>0$ then $\int e^{|x|}dx=\int e^{x}dx=e^{x}+C$.

When $x=0$ then $\int e^{|x|}dx=\int e^{0}dx=x+C$.

When $x<0$ then $\int e^{|x|}dx=\int e^{-x}dx=-e^{-x}+C$.

$2^{nd}$ process:

We know that $e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+...\infty$.

Therefore we can say that $e^{|x|}=1+|x|+\frac{(|x|)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(|x|)^{3}}{3!}+...\infty$.

Therefore we can integrate now $e^{|x|}dx$ easily from this expansion.

$\int e^{|x|}dx=\int 1dx+ \int |x|dx+ \int\frac{(|x|)^{2}}{2!}dx+ \int\frac{(|x|)^{3}}{3!}dx+...\infty$.

Therefore,

$\int e^{|x|}dx= x+C_1 + \frac{x^{2}sgn(x)}{2}+C_2 + \frac{x^{3}}{6}+C_3 + \frac{x^{4}sgn(x)}{24}+C_4 +...\infty$

But I am confused whether my $2^{nd}$ process is correct or not. Also in the $2^{nd}$ process I am not getting the option to write the integral constant $i.e.$ $+C$, because $C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4+...$ will be equal to $+C$ . Wolfram Alpha is giving an answer which is different from my methods.

Please help me out with this integral.

Comment: You are on the right track. For a piecewise continuous function there must always exist a continuous antiderivative. In the first process you would connect the multiple $C$s by saying $$e^0+C_1=-e^0+C_2$$ The middle term is incorrect since integration of continuous functions always ignores what happens at single points (an integral $\int_0^0$ would make no sense being anything nonzero). For the second method you wouldn't need multiple $C$s for integrating each term in a Taylor series. They would condense into one $C$ at the beginning.

Comment: Yes you are correct @NinadMunshi. But actually I have not understood the solution of Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: What is the solution of WolframAlpha and which part doesn't match your methods?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x})((e^{x}-1)^{2}sgn(x)-2e^{x}+e^{2x}-1$. This is the solution of wolfram alpha

Comment: Can you understand the solution of Wolfram Alpha @NinadMunshi. If then please explain me.

Comment: WA has its own algorithm but it works out the same way if you plot it by cases. I would've done it your way and after matching constants I would've had the compact shorthand $$(e^{|x|}-1)\operatorname{sgn}(x)+C$$ which I think looks simpler.

Comment: Yes might be @NinadMunshi.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=|x|$ then $du=\frac x{|x|}dx\operatorname{sgn}(x)dx$ for $x\neq 0$ or equivalently $dx=\operatorname{sgn}(x)du.$ Then
$$\int e^{|x|}dx=\int \operatorname{sgn}(x)e^udu$$
Since $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is just a constant, we can take it out and have
$$\operatorname{sgn}(x)\int e^udu=\operatorname{sgn}(x)e^u+C=\operatorname{sgn}(x)e^{|x|}+C.$$

Comment: Your process seems to be correct @Bob Dobbs. But I can't understand the process of Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti Maybe the inventors of WA knows what's going on. You should ask them.

Answer (score 1):

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
|x|= x\sign(x),\sign(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$$

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\int e^{|x|}dx=
\int e^{x\sign(x)}dx=
\int\frac{e^u}{\sign(x)}du=
\frac{1}{\sign(x)}\int e^udu=
\frac{e^u}{\sign(x)}+C=
\frac{e^{x\sign(x)}}{\sign(x)}+C=
\frac{xe^{|x|}}{|x|}+C$$

Comment: $\operatorname{sgn}$ is usually the correct term in this context.